# Elastic/OpenSearch: query composite IP range like 123.[16-31].0.*

Tags: elasticsearch, range, ipv4, opensearch

I want to run a query that filters out an IP range like `123.[16-31].0.*` (16 and 31 are included). Generic example:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_phrase": {
          "somefield": "somevalue"
        }
      },
      "must_not": {
        ... ip filter ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do I write the `must_not` part?

A solution that seems to work is to put 16 ranges in the `must_not`:

```
      "must_not": [
        {
          "range": {
            "host.ip": {
              "gte": "123.16.0.0",
              "lte": "123.16.0.255"
            }
          }
        },
.... same for 17 until 30
        {
          "range": {
            "host.ip": {
              "gte": "123.31.0.0",
              "lte": "123.31.0.255"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
```

but takes so much to type down. I would love to use a regex like:

```
      "must_not": {
        "regexp": {
          "host.ip": "123.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|30|31).0.*"
        }
      }
```

but obviously it fails with `Can only use regexp queries on keyword and text fields - not on [host.ip] which is of type [ip]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating 16 ranges is the fastest solution. But if you don't run this request too many times and prefer to trade some CPU time for programmers time you can convert `ip` field into a `keyword` field using runtime mapping. They way, you will be able to treat this field like any other text field. So, you can do something like this:

```
DELETE test
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "host": {
        "properties": {
          "ip": {
            "type": "ip"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_bulk?refresh
{"index":{}}
{"host":{"ip":"123.16.0.1"}}
{"index":{}}
{"host":{"ip":"123.16.1.0"}}
{"index":{}}
{"host":{"ip":"124.16.0.1"}}

POST test/_search
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "host.ip_string": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "script": {
        "source": "emit(doc['host.ip'].value);"
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "host.ip_string": "123.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|30|31).0.*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

or even better something like this:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "host.ip_string": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "script": {
        "source": "emit(doc['host.ip'].value);"
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "host.ip_string": "123\\.<16-31>\\.0\\..*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @imotov! A compromise that works for me is to use the 16 ranges in hard-coded queries, and your runtime mapping conversion when testing manually... Can't say I like seeing 16 ranges in a file, but what works is what works!

Comment: @SuZirboni would you mind marking this question as answered then?